# How important is ergodic theory in fundamentally understanding statistical mechanics?

Tags: ergodic-theory, statistical-mechanics

Recently, I realized the physics course in my uni has been lacking mathematical rigor and I have been attempting to compensate by adjoining it with personal mathematical study. For example, learning some functional analysis before going into quantum mechanics. Does ergodic theory have the same importance in statistical mechanics?

In other words, is the understanding of ergodic theory fundamental for understanding the math that underlies statistical mechanics like, for example, Hilbert spaces in quantum mechanics?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's an amazing subject that's fun to learn!

Comment: I don't think it is fundamental to have taken courses to have an introduction to statistical mechanics, just knowing the basic definitions should be enough. However, I believe that knowing the techniques and ideas of ergodic theory can really help you shape the ideas of statistical mechanics, there are many connections between the areas.

Comment: For a quick motivation, I suggest you read the introduction of the lecture notes by O. Sarig in Thermodynamic Formalism (which is connected to both ergodic theory and statistical mechanics) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.406.5732&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a usual quantum mechanics course, you will see Hilbert spaces everywhere even if the course is not mathematical enough to point them out and not rigorous enough to prove some important things that follow from them about operator spectra and bases and what have you. The situation with ergodic theory and a typical introductory course in statistical mechanics is a bit different. Generally, in stat mech one can neatly decouple the assumption of ergodicity from its consequences. In other words, usually the starting point is to *assume* a closed system is ergodic and explore the consequences of that.

It would certainly be an advantage for you to have a mathematical understanding of what ergodicity is, and it would also be good to have an intuition for when there will be ergodicity breaking. However the issue of whether the assumption of ergodicity can be proven correct for an underlying dynamical system (which would be what ergodic theory would bear on most directly) is usually not treated with much importance. The macroscopic consequences that are more of interest involve different concepts. (The mathematical structures you might see lurking here are manifolds. And in fact there are strong connections between statistical mechanics and quantum mechanics.) [**EDIT** I'm wrong here. Ergodic theory does have important applications in the thermodynamics. See Robert Israel's comment]

None of this is to discourage you from learning the subject if you're interested, of course.

Comment: Ergodicity of time evolution of a many-body mechanical system is notoriously difficult to prove; only a few such systems, such as Sinai's billiards, have been proven ergodic.  On the other hand, ergodicity under space translations is very important in the thermodynamic limit of equilibrium statistical mechanics.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : You are, of course, completely right. However, one should point out spatial ergodicity would be relevant for the OP if he were to follow a mathematical physics class on statistical mechanics, not a typical theoretical physics one.